# Using a slider under another mouse area QML / QT

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I am designing an UI interface in Qt where one of the pages can swipe between views. I have defined a `SwipeArea` region in the whole screen (which is a `MouseArea` I defined in another QML file), to be able to swipe between pages, with the property `propagateComposedEvents` set to `true` so that I can swipe between pages, and still being able to click on all buttons.

The problem comes when using a `Slider`. Apparently it can't get these mouse events, and I can't interact with it because when I click on the screen it starts the swiping handler. Any idea of how can I solve this?

This is where I define the `SwipeArea.qml` code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

MouseArea {
    property point origin
    property bool ready: false
    signal move(int x, int y)
    signal swipe(string direction)

    propagateComposedEvents: true


    onPressed: {
        drag.axis = Drag.XAndYAxis
        origin = Qt.point(mouse.x, mouse.y)
    }

    onPositionChanged: {
        switch (drag.axis) {
        case Drag.XAndYAxis:
            if (Math.abs(mouse.x - origin.x) > 16) {
                drag.axis = Drag.XAxis
            }
            else if (Math.abs(mouse.y - origin.y) > 16) {
                drag.axis = Drag.YAxis
            }
            break
        case Drag.XAxis:
            move(mouse.x - origin.x, 0)
            break
        case Drag.YAxis:
            move(0, mouse.y - origin.y)
            break
        }
    }

    onReleased: {
        switch (drag.axis) {
        case Drag.XAndYAxis:
            canceled(mouse)
            break
        case Drag.XAxis:
            swipe(mouse.x - origin.x < 0 ? "left" : "right")
            break
        case Drag.YAxis:
            swipe(mouse.y - origin.y < 0 ? "up" : "down")
            break
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the `main.qml` where I use it:

```
Item {
        id: content
        width: root.width * itemDataLength
        height:parent.height

        property double k: (content.width - root.width) / (img.width - root.width)

        Repeater {
            id:repeater
            model: itemDataLength
            width:parent.width
            height:parent.height

            Loader{
                id:loader
                width:parent.width / 2
                x: root.width * index
                height:parent.height
                source:loaderItems[index]

            }
        }
    }

 SwipeArea {
        id: mouse
        anchors.fill: parent
        onMove: {
            content.x = (-root.width * currentIndex) + x
        }
        onSwipe: {

            switch (direction) {
            case "left":
                if (currentIndex === itemDataLength - 1) {
                    currentIndexChanged()
                }
                else {
                    currentIndex++
                }
                break
            case "right":
                if (currentIndex === 0) {
                    currentIndexChanged()
                }
                else {
                    currentIndex--
                }
                break
            }
        }
        onCanceled: {
            currentIndexChanged()
        }
    }
```

Maybe important to add, my slider code:

```
  Slider {
        id: slider
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        updateValueWhileDragging:true
        activeFocusOnPress:true

        style: SliderStyle {
            id:sliderStyle

            //Slider handler
            handle: Rectangle {
                id:handler
                width: 22
                height: 44
                radius:2
                antialiasing: true

                Image{
                    source:"icons/slidercenter.png"
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                }
            }

            //Slider Groove
            groove: Item {
                id:slidergroove
                implicitHeight: 50
                implicitWidth: temperaturePage.width -50

         }
     }
  }
```

I appreciate any help or opinion, and thank you in advance!

Comment: Dis you get solution of this?